# What thing should be excluded when posting an open-source project on GitHub

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, open-source, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to add an open-source, ruby-on-rails project to GitHub.  I would like to make it as easy as possible for others to contribute, while protecting sensitive information.

In addition to:

- database passwords
- API keys

Which things are best suited to environment variable  (e.g. `ENV['MY_API_KEY']`)?

In addition to:

- `config/database.yml` (thanks house9)

Which things are best included in the `.gitignore` file?

What gems or other tools are helpful in this regard?

Should sensitive accounts (e.g. 'admin') be created directly in the database in the production environment?

Answer (score 1):

I would put `config/database.yml` in `.gitignore` and have a `config/database.yml.example` file for people to use

consider using dotenv

- https://rubygems.org/gems/dotenv-rails
- https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv

the default .env file can have 'stubbed' out values that will at least let someone fire it up in development and then it can be replaced when deploying with actual values